# MS ui automation elements and web applications

Tags: c#, web-applications, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I want to automate a web application. I'm already working with microsoft ui automation library. My problem is that i can not find a unique identifier for automationElements in the web page, automationIdproperty is always empty. any help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to work with the AutomationID property. There are other properties that may be unique to each control. If the control in question is a 'simple' one, such as a button, hyperlink or a textblock, the `Name` property is often derived from the text value of the control. There's also obviously the `ClassName` property. You can also use the *order* of controls in a web page as a method of recognizing each one.

Finally, if there's no other solution and you simply cannot find any helpful property, you can use the location of the control on the screen. You can either use the `FindFirst()` method on an `AutomationElement` querying the `BoundingRectangle` property, or get all values for this property from a list of `AutomationElements` and check if a control is in a given range.

Comment: thank you for your help. I think I will use the location as you said!

Comment: I've tried to use the location but the bounding rectangle property changes as I change the size of the page. Is there a way to have an absolute location, something fixed?

Comment: @amy Yes, the Bounding Rectangle property naturally changes according to the page size. I suggested that you use it dynamically in your code. This way you can query a given AutomationElement and tell if it's above or below another AutomationElement. This is of course only useful if your elements are in a static order.